# Detecting smooth/momentum scrolling that's cancelable with a tap?

Tags: javascript, scroll

In all the mobile browsers I've tried, when you momentum scroll, you can tap anywhere to stop the scroll. Normally, when you tap the page, the events that get triggered are pointerdown, pointerup, and click. When you tap to stop momentum scroll, the events are pointerdown and pointerup, with no click event.

I want to detect whether a pointerdown event should lead to a click event or if it's to stop momentum scroll. This is to fix a bug where Chrome sometimes fires a click event when you tap to stop momentum scroll (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1474135). E.g.:

```
  let isScrolling = false;
  let lastScrollTime = -Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  window.addEventListener(
    'scroll',
    () => {
      isScrolling = true;
      lastScrollTime = performance.now();
    },
    {
      capture: true,
      passive: true,
    },
  );
  window.addEventListener(
    'scrollend',
    () => {
      isScrolling = false;
    },
    {
      capture: true,
      passive: true,
    },
  );

  let lastCancelClickTime = -Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  window.addEventListener(
    'pointerdown',
    () => {
      // This should detect whether the pointerdown is to stop momentum scroll,
      // but it doesn't always work
      if (isScrolling && performance.now() - lastScrollTime < 100) {
        lastCancelClickTime = performance.now();
      }
    },
    { capture: true },
  );
  window.addEventListener(
    'click',
    event => {
      if (performance.now() - lastCancelClickTime < 500) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
    },
    { capture: true },
  );
```

The condition `isScrolling && performance.now() - lastScrollTime < 100` is unreliable because 100 is too long for devices with momentum scroll enabled and too short for devices without momentum scroll. I also can't reliably detect whether momentum scroll is enabled. Is there a better way to detect whether a pointerdown event occurred because the user wanted to stop momentum scroll?